# Which single substance among Potassium and Phosphate has the greatest osmotic activity in the Intracellular fluid?

Tags: cell-biology, human-physiology, osmosis

My physiology textbook mentions that potassium has the greatest concentration ( 155 mEq/L ) in the Intracellular fluid and that I thought would make it the most osmotically active but the answer given is **phosphate** and I can't understand how this is the case. Is it because a compound of phosphorus would contribute more osmoles than potassium?

Comment: I don't have an answer, though I have a suspicion it may have something to do with the charge of their ionic forms. Potassium ions have +1 charge. Phosphate ions (the most common form of phosphorus in cells) have a -3 charge.

Comment: Can you provide a short quote from your actual textbook?

Comment: @BryanKrause actually this is a review question given at the end of the chapter. In the chapter they have given the respective concentrations of potassium, phosphate and other ions only and explained about osmosis and other transport mechanisms in a cell.

Comment: @acvill I've thought of a solution but I am not sure.Osmosis is defined as the movement of water from the region of its higher concentration to lower concentration through a semipermeable membrane which is **impermeable to the solute**. Although potassium is more concentrated in ICF(155 mEq/L) it can pass through the membrane whereas phosphate which is less concentrated (90 mEq/L) cannot pass the membrane and hence is more osmotically active. Can this be the reason ?

Comment: I'm guessing if you go to the textbook section that the question pertains to you'll find what specifically the author is wanting you to take away.

Comment: @Bryan In the chapter there is actually no reference to anything called osmotic activity which is the reason I cannot understand on what factors osmotic activity might depend on.I think this a inference based question in which we ourselves have to find the cause based on the facts given within the chapter.Can you please check out the comment I made earlier and if that might be the possible explanation of the question.